# Multiple proxy works locally but not working on server react

Tags: reactjs, fetch, http-status-code-404, http-proxy-middleware

1. I install this package **http-proxy-middleware** to consume multiple end points in react 17.0
2. I placed **setup/setupProxy.js** file **src**/
3. **Problem is** multiple proxies called locally working fine, but the problem is when I deployed the build on the server or run the build locally it gives **404 not found**

**Info**

1. There is no .env file in my project is it OK?
2. After adding homepage: "." it gives enable javascript error
   I try multiple browsers but still got the error when I run the build locally

**setupProxy.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
app.use(
createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: 'https://server1.com', // API endpoint 1
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': '',
  },
  headers: {
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
  },
})
);
app.use(
createProxyMiddleware('/control', {
  target: 'https://server2.com', // API endpoint 2
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/control': '',
  },
  headers: {
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
  },
})
);
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": ".....",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "homepage": ".",
 "dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"antd": "^4.16.13",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"bootstrap": "5.1.3",
"http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.4",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"material-ui-color": "^1.2.0",
"material-ui-popup-state": "^2.0.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"rc-color-picker": "^1.2.6",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
"react-bootstrap-range-slider": "^3.0.3",
"react-bootstrap-timezone-picker": "^2.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-icons": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-switch": "^6.0.0",
"react-time-picker": "^4.4.4",
"react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
"rgb-hex": "^4.0.0",
"web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
 ]
 },
 "browserslist": {
 "production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
  ],
 "development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
   ]
  }
 }
```

**login**
Using fetch package

```
   await fetch('/api/v4/auth/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
   Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
```